# Using mathdesign's math font with another text font

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to use a math font provided by the mathdesign package for mathematics, along with another text font, under pdflatex ? If it is, is there an easy way to do it ?

More precisely, I try to use the font math that goes with Charter when using

```
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
```

and some variant of New Century Schoolbook, for example the one that comes with

```
\usepackage{fouriernc}
```

My understanding of (La)TeX fonts is low ; until now, the only way I used them is to add some package in the header and magically the font changed. I tried to look at [the LaTeX font guide](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) but it only emphasized the fact that it is more complicated than I thought.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start by loading mathdesign, afterwards you may change the text font. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{fnc}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it seems to work. Thanks ! Now, how did you found out the "fnc" ? I suppose it stands for "FourierNC", but where is the logic ?

Comment: @Georg: I found it reading `fouriernc.sty`. Have a look inside it, that file is very short. Find it by `kpsewhich fouriernc.sty` or another search feature on you local drive.